# PHP - Does if/elseif behave like stacked if statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

Does if/elseif behave like stacked if statements?

```
if( $a == 2 )
{
   $a = 0;
   $b = 2;
}
elseif( $b == 2 )
{
   echo "Cool?";
}
```

Comment: `Why don't you try yourself ?`

Comment: Because I'm bored and felt like human interaction in the form of getting flamed for asking a stupid question.

Comment: Edited your question . eh ? ;)

Comment: Yessir!  I don't enjoy coming off as a complete maroon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis that the `else` is there, no, it won't work.

For it to work how you wish it to, you'd need to remove the else and just use 2 `if` statements, such as;

```
// Set default values;
$a = 2;
$b = 0;

// Check $a
if( $a == 2 )
{
    // Change values
    $a = 0;
    $ b = 2;
}

// Check $b, which is now 2 due to the condition matching above
if( $b == 2 )
{
   echo "Cool?";
}
```

I believe you're slightly missing the point with the else.

It is used for condition matching, to confirm multiple possibilies.

For example, let's imagine a lottery, where the prize money is split into ranges;

Numbers 01 - 10 = $5.
Numbers 11 - 20 = $10. 
Numbers 21 - 30 = $20.

You're code could look something like

```
<?php
$random_result = mt_rand(0, 30);

if ($random_number > 20) {
    $amount = 20;
}
else if ($random_number > 10) {
    $amount = 10;
}
else
{
    $amount = 5;
}
echo 'The jackpot for today was $' . $amount . '!';
```

Comment: I don't think I am missing the point at all. i just thought it was interesting that I couldn't decide, based on my experience, whether if/elseif behaves like stacking if statements (such as you've illustrated I could do to satisfy the result I was inquiring about).  Thank you for the extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, if `$a` is `2` when the `if` checks, the `elseif` will *not* be checked. You should consider the entire `if...elseif` section a *single* statement where the first condition that evaluates as true stops the rest from being checked.

If the `elseif` were a separate `if`, then yes, it would output `Cool?`.

But it's not.

So it won't.

Answer (score 1):

The `elseif` portion of your code will not execute if any `if/elseif...` prior to it are true.  The `if/elseif/...` blocks execute in order, and once one of them is true, the others are not considered.